# wrong precision for double values

Tags: c++, fortran, double, fortran77

I need to convert a Fortran code into a C++ one and I have the following problem:

I'm trying to compute a double value named `R12` with both Fortran 77 and C++ languages but I obtained two values very close each others but with two different precision . here is my Fortran code :

```
R12 = sqrt(95699.68D0+1123.6D0*flx) - 408.99D0
```

with `double flx = 192.9D0`. The value I obtain is `R12 = 149.97522253177789`

I do the same with C++:

```
R12 = sqrt(95699.68+1123.6*flx) - 408.99 ;
```

The value I obtain here is `R12 = 149.97522253177794`.

Can you guys please help me to find where this difference is from, cause it's very important for my work to have the exact precision

Comment: Define "exact precision"? Using floating point values you will never have "exact precision", and for irrational numbers you would need infinite precision anyway. `double` has 15-17 numbers of precision and that is what you have here.

Comment: You can also read more about this here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon

Comment: Have you checked that (1) the result of the multiplication is identical in both languages? (2) the result of the addition is identical in both languages? (3) the result of `sqrt` is identical in both languages? You need to drill down to the essence of the problem *before* asking on SO.

Comment: I've checked it before, the sqrt function give the same result for both languages, the problem comes from the soustraction between sqrt and 408.99

Comment: Check, if you haven't already, that you have told your compiler to use IEEE arithmetic in both the Fortran and C++ code.  By default most Fortran compilers, in compliance with that language's long-standing standard(s), do not require adherence to IEEE's standard for floating-point arithmetic, which was defined long after Fortran started crunching numbers.  I'm not sure what C++ compilers are required to do but I suspect that they too can play fast and loose with f-p arithmetic unless told explicitly to behave themselves.

Answer (score 5):

With double precision, you have [52 bits (roughly 15 decimals)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) of significand precision. In your case this is:

Fortran:

```
0.14997522253177789e3
                ^
```

C++

```
0.14997522253177794e3
                ^
```

You can see that both results are identical up to the 15th digit. My guess is that C++ and Fortran apply a different conversion (rounding) to the decimal system.

In Fortran 2003+ you can give a `ROUND` specifier to `write`:

```
program test

  write(*,*)                     'Default    ', sqrt(95699.68D0+1123.6D0*192.9D0) - 408.99D0
  write(*,*,round='UP')          'UP         ', sqrt(95699.68D0+1123.6D0*192.9D0) - 408.99D0
  write(*,*,round='DOWN')        'DOWN       ', sqrt(95699.68D0+1123.6D0*192.9D0) - 408.99D0
  write(*,*,round='ZERO')        'ZERO       ', sqrt(95699.68D0+1123.6D0*192.9D0) - 408.99D0
  write(*,*,round='NEAREST')     'NEAREST    ', sqrt(95699.68D0+1123.6D0*192.9D0) - 408.99D0

end program
```

results in

```
 Default   149.97522253177794     
 UP        149.97522253177795     
 DOWN      149.97522253177794     
 ZERO      149.97522253177794     
 NEAREST   149.97522253177794
```

Comment: yean i know but the thing is that there is a lot of arithmetic instructions after that one, so the little difference is getting bigger at the end of my program

Comment: My guess is that the numbers are identical in *binary representation*, but you should check that! BTW: I get exactly the same result in Fortran as you get in C++...